# How to adaptively split an image into regions and set a different text orientation for each one?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

Input-Sample

[image: Input-Sample]

I am trying to pre-process my images in order to improve the ocr quality. However, I am stuck with a problem.
The Images I am dealing with contain different text orientations within the same image (2 pages, 1st is vertical, the 2nd one is horizontally oriented and they are scanned to the same image.

The text direction is automatically detected for the first part. nevertheless, the rest of the text from the other page is completely missed up.
I was thinking of creating a zonal template to detect the regions of interest but I don't know how.
Or automatically detect the border and split the image adaptively then flip the splitted part to achieve the required result.
I could set splitting based on a fixed pixel height but it is not constant as well.

```
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI, RIL
import cv2
from PIL import Image
with PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
    filePath = r'sample.jpg'
img = Image.open(filePath)
api.SetImage(img)
boxes = api.GetComponentImages(RIL.TEXTLINE, True)
print('Found {} textline image components.'.format(len(boxes)))
for i, (im, box, _, _) in enumerate(boxes):
    # im is a PIL image object
    # box is a dict with x, y, w and h keys
    api.SetRectangle(box['x'], box['y'], box['w'], box['h'])
    ocrResult = api.GetUTF8Text()
    conf = api.MeanTextConf()
    for box in boxes:
     box = boxes[0][1]
     x = box.get('x')
     y = box.get('y')
     h = box.get('h')
     w = box.get('w')
     cimg = cv2.imread(filePath)
     crop_img = cimg[y:y+h, x:x+w]
     cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_img)
     cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7RLs.png)
as you can see i can apply an orientation detection but I wount get any meaningful text out of such an image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you have so far, some example input images, and the desired outputs for these.

Comment: @HansHirse I added an Input sample.

Comment: please check the code and the output!!

Answer (score 0):

Try Tesseract API method `GetComponentImages` and then `DetectOrientationScript` on each component image.

Comment: Thanks, please check the edited version of my question.
Maybe you can help me further.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: the problem is, if use an orientation's detection, the upper part of the image will be handled correctly. However, the lower part will not processed as it should.

Comment: Once you get all the component images, run the orientation's detection on each of them individually, rotate those that need to, based on the detected orientation, and then finally run recognition process on each image. See API Examples: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample#getcomponentimages-example

Comment: Can you please check the output image at the end of the question?